# setting specific interval time on python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Python project. The code will refresh at a specific time and fetch new records and update the database. What I'm trying to achieve is to refresh every 15 minutes or 30 minutes. The below code is good but only fetches new records once per day at 00.00am.

```
def check_schedule_task(self):
        # update group member list at 00:00 am every morning
        t = time.localtime()
        if t.tm_hour == 0 and t.tm_min <= 1:
            # update group member
            Log.debug('update group member list everyday')
            self.db.delete_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_LIST())
            self.db.delete_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_USER_LIST())
            self.db.create_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_LIST(), Constant.TABLE_GROUP_LIST_COL)
            self.db.create_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_USER_LIST(), Constant.TABLE_GROUP_USER_LIST_COL)
self.wechat.fetch_group_contacts()
```

I tried the below but it's refreshing every second

```
def check_schedule_task(self):
            # update group member list at 00:00 am every morning
            t = time.localtime()
            if t.tm_min == 15 or 30 or 45 or 00:
                # update group member
                Log.debug('update group member list everyday')
                self.db.delete_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_LIST())
                self.db.delete_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_USER_LIST())
                self.db.create_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_LIST(), Constant.TABLE_GROUP_LIST_COL)
                self.db.create_table(Constant.TABLE_GROUP_USER_LIST(), Constant.TABLE_GROUP_USER_LIST_COL)
    self.wechat.fetch_group_contacts()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `if t.tm_min == 15 or 30 or 45 or 00:` is incorrect.

What you want to write instead is

```
if t.tm_min in (15,30,45,00):
```

Despite what you may think, your version is not how comparing to multiple values works in Python. The comparison will always evaluate to true since even if the first comparison is false, the rest of the values are truthy. You instead want to check if that list of number contains your variable.

Comment: You should also show the `if var==15 or var==30 or var==45 or var==00` approach.

Comment: if t.tm_min in (15,30,45,00):  > this works perfectly, thanks brother